# A trigger to automatically deactivate the old record upon renewal

Tags: sql-server-2005, triggers, exists

I am renewing a record. I need to create a trigger that will automatically deactivate the old record. Records are renewed into a new table not the same. Values between the newly insert record and original record are match by 2 columns, let's say col1 and col2

```
ALTER TRIGGER TR_On_Renewed_Customer
ON CustomerTable2
FOR INSERT
AS
// psudeo code
// Deactive the old record in customertable1 
// if match is found between CustomerTable2 and 
// CustomerTable1 based on col1 and col2, then update Active ='No'
```

I am a little bit lost how to use EXIST in this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to use the special `Inserted` table, which contains the rows that were just impacted by the `INSERT` operation that caused the trigger to fire.

```
UPDATE c1
    SET Active = 'No'
    FROM Inserted i
        INNER JOIN CustomerTable1 c1
            ON i.col1 = c1.col1
                AND i.col2 = c1.col2
```

Comment: I like this query but can I use If Exist which can be somewhat more elegant. Thank you for the answer though and I will use this query.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "more elegant", but I think the JOIN operation will be better in this case.